# Motorola Droid Turbo

Tags: speaker

This is a replacement phone. Now on this one, I can't hear anyone unless I put them on speaker. Even though I've had the phone for three days, I had to do a factory reset on it already and that didn't cure it. Suggestions?

Comment: What is a "replacement phone"? You had the same phone before and you had to return it for a new one? Or the phone was refurbished? Why did you factory reset it? What does this have to do with three days? This sounds like a hardware problem where you need to return the handset.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the speaker is not working on the low volume it works on when it's on call. It is a kernel or hardware problem. Resetting will not help. You have to flash a kernel yourself, or ask for replacement if even that does not help

Comment: I forgot to mention that I gave the volume turned all the way up. What is a flash kernel ?

Comment: Flashing a kernel is to manually install a custom kernel. If you don't know what that means, then I don't suggest you do that. I recommend you ask for a replacement telling them your problem. If that doesn't work, I will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your speaker is most likely broken. Try to take it to a repair shop to get it fixed up, if you haven't already.